# Solution-wide TODO list for C++ projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there any working add-in, fixing the broken (only showing entries for the current file) task window for Visual Studio C++ projects?

These could be one-trick solutions or functionality contained in some larger add-in. I wasn't able to find such a thing.

Comment: Global search for todo?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: For me mostly 2013, perhaps 2012. Even 2015, but I don't know too much yet about this IDE.

Comment: Multiple comments online suggest that "for performance reasons" this TODO list works for all files in VB, for all open files in C#, and for an active file in C++. 
However, in my 2015 Community in C++ project it shows TODOs in all open files. Still not what you wanted. Maybe I should write an add-in :)

Comment: @Michael - apparently, VS 2015 solved that issue :(

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is a working Visual Studio extension on visualstudiogallery that does that:
[FeinTasks](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c5d16a00-fe89-4a9e-8fba-a5c1a9f38841)
[image]

Comment: Is there something similar for VS 2017?

Comment: @Electrix - isn't this feature working out of the box for VS 2017?

Comment: It may be a bug, but it isn't. At least for some languages (like Python or C++) it doesn't work for entire solution, but only for opened files. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/50630/vs2017-task-list-entire-solution-filter-do-not-wor.html.